# Entity Framework - Loading only certain rows in navigational property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the classes

```
Address
PeopleAddress    //join table with a column called current
People           // my main table, with a IList<PeopleAddress>

modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
            .HasMany<PeopleAddress>(m => m.CurrentAddresses)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.PeopleId);
```

I (always) want to load only PeopleAddress's in people where PeopleAddress.Current == 1.
rows with PeopleAddress.Current == 0 is not required for the application. 
How do I achieve this? Is this possible? Thank you.

PS: I  cant not use `Include` as the context is instantiated in a lot of places and I need to do it in  `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

Answer (score 0):

For this to work lazy loading should be disabled giving you full control of which data is loaded.

Do the query on the PeopleAddress table and make sure the People data gets loaded as well via the navigational property in PeopleAddress.

```
public virtual People People { get; set; }

PeopleAddress.Include(pa => pa.People).Where(pa => pa.Current == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
context.People.Include("PeopleAddress")
              .Select(t=> new { t,
                                PeopleAddress= t.PeopleAddress
                                                .Where(p=>p.Current==1)});
```